# Parsing NSMutableString By Number Of Instances

Tags: objective-c, nsmutablestring

I have an NSMutableString that contains a lot of data. A short example of it is:

> MP3: name length album
>
> MP3: name length album
>
> MP3: name length album
>
> MP3: name length album

Now, what I'm trying to accomplish is to parse the string to contain only the first 3 MP3 data sets. So once the fourth instance of "MP3:" is found, stop parsing.

I've tried multiple thing to accomplish this, but I've been staring at it too long and am starting to go goofy. If it was an array it would be simple but unfortunately it's a string. Does anyone know how to accomplish the logic behind this?
To add more clarity: I would still like the first the MP3's to appear. They will be different every time so I can't do a subStringToIndex.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To do this efficiently, assuming the input string is very long (containing thousands of lines after the first three), you need to avoid using `componentsSeparatedByString:`.

Instead, find the first three newlines in the string, by using `rangeOfString:` repeatedly.

```
NSString *input = @"MP3: line1\nMP3: line2\nMP3: line3\nMP3: line4\nMP3: line5\n";
NSUInteger lineStartLocation = 0;
NSUInteger inputLength = input.length;
for (int i = 0; i < 3; ++i) {
    NSRange searchRange = NSMakeRange(lineStartLocation, inputLength - lineStartLocation);
    NSRange newlineRange = [input rangeOfString:@"\n" options:0 range:searchRange];
    if (newlineRange.location == NSNotFound) {
        // Not enough lines in input!
        break;
    } else {
        lineStartLocation = newlineRange.location + 1;
    }
}

NSString *top3 = [input substringToIndex:lineStartLocation];
NSLog(@"top3 = %@", top3);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
NSArray *lines = [data componentsSeparatedByString:@"\n"];

for (NSUInteger i = 0, count = 0; i < lines.count && count < 3; i++) {
    NSString *line = lines[i];
    NSRange range = [line rangeOfString:@"MP3:"];

    if (range.location == 0 && range.length == @"MP3:".length) {
        // parsing
        count++;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
NSString * stringToParse = @"MP3: hola MP3: pfff MP3: cosas MP3: hello";

NSArray * arrayStringParsed = [stringToParse componentsSeparatedByString:@"MP3:"];
```

And the results is and array:

<__NSArrayM 0x15fb2f80>(
,
 hola ,
 pfff ,
 cosas ,
 hello
)

First element doesn't have anything but the other 4 are parsed and you can work with them.